# ¿Cómo devuelvo datos en un where … case incluyendo nulos?

Tags: tsql

Necesito obtener todos los registros de una tabla cuando `[tabla].[columna]` es igual a `@parametro`, con la siguiente excepción: cuando el parámetro es igual a 0, necesito obtener todos los registros de tabla, incluyendo aquellos donde `[tabla].[columna]` es NULL.

He intentado hacerlo usando un `CASE` en el `WHERE`, esto funciona bien:

```
WHERE [tabla].[columna] = CASE @parametro WHEN 0 THEN [tabla].[columna] ELSE @parametro END
```

El problema es que cuando busco por `@parametro` igual a cero, trae todos los registros pero no aquellos donde `[tabla].[columna]` es NULL.

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

El campo de la tabla es de tipo entero (`int`), esto es en SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: ¿qué te devuelve esta consulta? ¿qué resultado esperas?

Comment: Esta consulta devuelve los valores que sean iguales al parámetro, es decir, sí el parámetro es igual a 1 devuelve los valores donde en la columna sean igual a 1, sí el parámetro es igual a 0 devuelve todos excepto los nulos. Lo que necesito es que devuelva todos incluyendo los nulos, cuando @parametro = 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No necesitas utilizar CASE, puedes hacerlo utilizando operadores lógicos.

```
DECLARE @parametro INT;

SELECT * FROM [tabla]
    WHERE @parametro = 0 OR @parametro = [tabla].[columna]
```

Aquí, si `@parametro` es 0, la expresión lógica retorna siempre verdadero y trae todos los registros, pero si parametro distinto de cero, traera los registros cuyo `[tabla].[columna]` sean iguales a `@parametro`.

Comment: Si necesito obtener todos los registro cuyo [tabla].[columna] es igual al parametro y sí, excepto cuando el parametro es igual a 0, en ese caso necesito TODOS incluyendo los nulos, gracias @rnrneverdies

Comment: esta ultima edición que realizaste es lo que necesitaba, muchas gracias, el resultado que esperaba es este: cuando el parámetro = 0 devolviera todos los resultados incluyendo los nulos, sí el parámetro es diferente a 0 solo los que coincidieran con ese valor, reitero mi agradecimiento, esto ultimo que publicaste como respuesta funciona de maravilla

Answer (score 0):

Según te entiendo con esto puedes capturar el valor cuando se a 0 que pasaría ser 100 en todo caso 2

```
DECLARE @VALOR INT
SET @VALOR = 0
SELECT CAMPO FROM TU_TABLA
WHERE CAMPO = CASE @VALOR WHEN 0 THEN 100 ELSE 2 END
```

En el caso sea vacío casteas tu parámetro o campo. Quiere decir cuando se a '' (vacío el campo) pasaría ser 100 en valor en todo caso 2

```
DECLARE @VALOR INT
SET @VALOR = ''
SELECT CAMPO FROM TU_TABLA
WHERE CAMPO = CASE CAST(@VALOR AS CHAR) WHEN 0 THEN 100 ELSE 2 END
```

Cuando sean nulos puedes usar el isnull remplazando por 0 u otro valor que desees, para esto asumo que cuando sea null sera 0 y como resultado tendría 100

```
DECLARE @VALOR INT
SET @VALOR = NULL
SELECT CAMPO FROM TU_TABLA
WHERE CAMPO = CASE ISNULL(@VALOR, 0) WHEN 0 THEN 100 ELSE 2 END
```

Comment: @hason, gracias por tu respuesta, en el caso expuesto es buscar valores cuando el parámetro tiene un valor ya sea 0 o mayor a 0 y los valores de la columna o campo son un valor o nulos

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @parametro INT;

IF @parametro = 0 BEGIN

    @parametro = NULL

END

SELECT * FROM [tabla] 
where [tabla].[columna] = ISNULL(@parametro,[tabla].[columna])
```